# Disable inventory-cache of ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook (no matter what, it is loggin into an other machine by SSH).

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini -l myhost1 myplaybook.yml
```

For that I am using an inventory-file.

```
myhost1 ansible_host=127.3.4.5 ansible_user=root ansible_password=Blabla9
```

If I change the ansible_passwort to something wrong it takes some time the playbook failes with an error.

I tried multiple things.

set shell variable:

```
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_CACHE=False
```

set ansible.cfg:

```
[inventory] 
cache=False
```

argument of ansible-playbook

```
flush-cache
```

Nothing worked. Any ideas??

Comment: I do not have a cache_plugin or any option about caching set in ansible.cfg. What is the default setting for it?